# Webforms InvalidOperationException when updating to httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, .net-4.7.2

I'm updating my old code to target 4.7.2 to create consistency across our applications. This one is an old webforms application. It's one aspx and one master file.

I used visual studio to change the target to 4.7.2 and this updated my csproj and webconfig

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
</system.web>
```

If I update the target framework to 4.7.2 I get the following error

```
[InvalidOperationException: Server could not create ASP.appskinmaster_master.]
   __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_31ycbdmm.Create_ASP_appskinmaster_master() in c:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\property_tax\cc244ff3\3e690eb6\App_Web_31ycbdmm.1.cs:0
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.CreateInstance() +31
   System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection) +826
   System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master() +56
   System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +302
```

I can update it all the way to 4.7.1 without issues.

Nothing listed here seem applicable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.7.1-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks for this! We're seeing the exact same issue on target framework 4.7.2 and 4.8. Your question might have saved me a day of troubleshooting :-)

Comment: What is the access modifier for the constructor of appskinmaster_master? I got the same error message for a single webforms page in our project when updating to 4.8, which had a protected constructor. When I changed it to public it worked.

Comment: thanks you @sigbjornlo but my constructor is `public AppSkinMaster(string baseLayoutUrl)`

Comment: @Jeff Are you missing a (public?) default constructor somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @sigbjornlo comment I found out that my default constructor was in fact protected. Thank you it's now on 4.8.